# How to check whether a value exists in xml file or not in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, .net-2.0

I am trying to check whether or not a string is exists in an xml file. If it does not exist, I have to add that string to the xml file.

My xml file looks like this:

```
  <Employee>
      <Emp>
        <Name id="1">   A     </Name>
        <Name id="2">   C     </Name>
        <Name id="3">   D     </Name>
       </Emp>
  </Employee>
```

And I want achieve:

```
dim str as string = "b" 
if str exists in "xmlfile"
    'do something
else
    'add string to file
end if
```

I am not really familiar LINQ at all but I understand that what I want to do is possible with LINQ. I have tried the following:

```
Dim employee = XElement.Load(someStream)
Dim emp = employee.Element("Emp")
If emp IsNot Nothing Then
    else
        'add string to xml file
End If
```

When I tried this I received the error: `XElement` is not declared.

Can any one suggest a way to do what I want in VB.NET without LINQ? Or if I have to use LINQ, can some provide an example?

I am using .net 2.0 (VB.NET)

Comment: If `XElement` is not declared, then you need `Imports System.Xml.Linq`  at the top.

Comment: I am sorry for not mentioning that even i tried this but it is giving error, i hope i might need to add any properties or something else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you want is something more like this:

```
Dim employeeData As XDocument
Dim employeeElements as List(Of XElement)
Dim numberOfNames as Integer = 0

employeeData = XDocument.Load(someStream)

employeeElements = (From elements In employeeData.Decendants()
                    Where (elements.Name.LocalName.ToString() = "Emp")
                    Select elements).ToList()

For Each employee In employeeElements
    If (employee.<Name>.Value = "B") Then
        numberOfNames = numberOfNames + 1
    End If
Next

If numberOfNames > 0 Then
    'Insert "B" into xml
End If
```

So that's an example using XDocument and interating though like user1512185 suggested with an example LINQ expression to get a list of XElements to iterate through.

This is a modification of something I do in one of my apps. However I don't insert into the xml so I'm not sure I can help you there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through Emp's children.  Right now, your code simply checks to see if the `<Emp>` element exists.  I presume what you actually want to do is check each `<Name>` element and see if its inner text contains the string you want.

You could also try using XmlDocument and XmlNode, which should be available in .NET 2.0 if XElement is giving you troubles.